# Created a table with new column names and when executing, an error message stating "Column Name Invalid" appears

Tags: sql

[image: Here is a copy of the code I am writing to create a table with column names]

I'm trying to add columns (OFFERING_STATUS, SEMESTERS_OFFERED) to this table but when I try to execute the query, it says that the column names are invalid. I don't understand why it would be invalid because there are no other matching column names since they are in the process of being created. I've tried refreshing the local cache but it still doesn't work. Could someone please explain to me why SQL is saying these names are invalid?

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: I doubt anything is wrong with what you have in the picture.  I think it is a problem off-screen.